Wiremock.net (C#) how to build a request matcher when the body is a an array of bytes
I need to build a WireMock.Net server for requests having body as bytes. I tried the matcher .WithBody combined with the converters Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (and GetString) but with no success.
Thank you for your help

There is an overload of the method WithBody accepting bytes array byte[]. See below example:
public class UnitTest1 : IDisposable
{
    private readonly WireMockServer _wireMock;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public UnitTest1()
    {
        byte[] bytes = [123, 167, 184]; // some random bytes
        _wireMock = WireMockServer.Start();
        _wireMock
            .Given(
                Request.Create()
                    .WithPath("/test")
                    .UsingGet())
            .RespondWith(
                Response.Create()
                    .WithStatusCode(200)
                    .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
                    .WithBody(bytes)
            );
        _client = _wireMock.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void Test1()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/test");
        var bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _wireMock?.Dispose();
    }
}

UPDATE
Another example using POST method and some arbitrary body in request:
public class UnitTest1 : IDisposable
{
    private readonly WireMockServer _wireMock;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public UnitTest1()
    {
        byte[] bytes = [123, 167, 184]; // some random bytes
        _wireMock = WireMockServer.Start();
        _wireMock
            .Given(
                Request.Create()
                    .WithPath("/testpost")
                    .UsingPost())
            .RespondWith(
                Response.Create()
                    .WithStatusCode(200)
                    .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
                    .WithBody(bytes)
            );
        _client = _wireMock.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void TestPost()
    {
        var someBytes = new byte[] { 123, 222, 151 };
        var requestContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(someBytes));
        var response = await _client.PostAsync("/testpost", requestContent);
        var bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _wireMock?.Dispose();
    }
}


Thank you @Turczyn but I am looking for a matcher to the body of the request. Your example is on how to build the response.

@YoucefKelanemer WithPath matches the path, UsingGet specifies what HTTP method will be matched. Body is irrelevant - define any body for the request, and this matcher will match it anyway, as long as you use /test path and GET method. You might want to use POST, then use UsingPost method on matcher.

@YoucefKelanemer Please see updated version

Thanks @Michał , I need to Taylor a response for different body content when the path is the same.
I have no control on the request coming to the stub.
